# recuperate fields of a json

Tags: json, angular, httprequest

I have a json like this :

```
[ {
    "id": 1,
    "libraryName": "lib1",
    "bookName": "book1",
    "bookPrice": 250.45,
    "unitSold": 305
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "libraryName": "lib1",
    "bookName": "book2",
    "bookPrice": 450.45,
    "unitSold": 150
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "libraryName": "lib1",
    "bookName": "book3",
    "bookPrice": 120.25,
    "unitSold": 400
}]
```

I want to recuperate all the bookNames of this json in a list without creating the method getBookNames (because I want a standard way for any field of the json) 
So, in the component.ts I used :

```
  sales:any;
  getSale () {
  this.service.getSales().subscribe(data=> {this.sales = data,
  console.log(this.sales.bookName)
  })
  }
```

It gives me undefined object in the console ! How can I solve this without creating a method getBookNames() ?

This is my class :

```
export interface Sale {
id: number
bookname : string
Libraryname: string
Bookprice : number
Unitsold : number
}
```

This is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Sale } from './Sale';
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyserviceService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getSales () {
return this.http.get<Sale>("http://localhost:8081/sales/all")
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data obtained from the API is an array. So you could use array [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to obtain a list of all the properties from the elements. Try the following

```js
sales: any;
unitsSold = [];

getSale () {
  this.service.getSales().subscribe(data=> {
    this.sales = data,
    console.log(data.map(item => item.bookName)); // <-- output: ['book1', 'book2', 'book3'];
    console.log(data.map(item => item.id)); // <-- output: [1, 2, 3];
    this.unitsSold = data.map(item => item.unitSold); // <-- [305, 150, 400]
  });
}
```

I don't see anything lost here to recuperate.